# How can I use jQuery to insert a new table row as the second row of a table?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff</td>
    </tr>
    // etc.
</table>
```

I want to insert a new table row into the above table so it is the second row. I know that I can use `prepend()` to insert the row as the 1st row, but I can't figure out how to insert it as the second row. Here is what I am using:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'get_new_table_row.php',
    success: function(data){
        $('table#myTable').prepend(data);                
    }
});
return false;
```

How can I modify this to make it insert the new row as the 2nd row in the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method and `:first` selector:

```
$('#myTable tr:first').after(data);
```

or:

```
$('#myTable tr').eq(0).after(data);
```